Getting PSSI to work via Rust on STM32
This will be more of a wider scoped question, as there is a lot that I am trying to understand here.
Context: I am attempting to communicate with the 16bit-parallel data interface of a MAX11046 ADC via an STM32H723ZG micro controller. At least to me, the PSSI (Parallel Synchronous Slave Interface) functionality provided by the STM32H723ZG seems to be best suited for this task.
Problem: I would prefer to program all of my embedded devices in Rust, but unfortunately, there is essentially no documentation or mention of PSSI in any of the STM32 HAL or PAC crates for Rust. The only thing I found was this.
In fact, there is surprisingly little information on using the PSSI in general.
I don't mind dealing with the registers directly and rolling my own peripheral around them --frankly it seems there is no other choice anyway. However, after some experimentation and reading, I have a few questions.
Questions
Does anyone have any experience with using Rust and the PSSI?
Due to the severe lack of online documentation regarding the problem at hand, anecdotal information may be helpful. Otherwise, any additional tips, suggestions and/or general comments are encouraged and appreciated.
Am I writing to and reading from the registers correctly?
I have a feeling I may be doing things incorrectly.
The documentation has the following:



PSSI_CR
PSSI_SR
PSSI_DR




Address Offset: 0x00
Address Offset: 0x04
Address Offset: 0x28


Reset Value: 0x4000 0000
Reset Value: 0x0000 0000
Reset Value: 0x0000 0000



Suppose I choose to set the PSSI configuration register as:
0000 0110 1011 0010 0000 0000 0000 0010
bit0 -----------------------------------> bit31
This is the same as the bytes [6, 178, 0, 2] and so ptr::write_volatile(PSSI_CR, 33600006) should configure the PSSI.
Why am I not getting only zero bytes when reading from the PSSI data register?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::ptr;
use panic_halt as _;

use stm32h7xx_hal::prelude::*;
use cortex_m_semihosting::hprintln;

const PSSI_CR: *mut u32 = 0x00 as *mut u32;
const PSSI_SR: *mut u32 = 0x04 as *mut u32;

const PSSI_DR: *const u32 = 0x28 as *const u32;

#[cortex_m_rt::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    unsafe {
        hprintln!("{:?}", ptr::read_volatile(PSSI_DR));
    }

    loop {}
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The output is 1687148601 and not 0 as I would expect.

Your initializer value for PSSI_CR doesn't make any sense to me. You're writing 1's to bits labeled as 'reserved' in the reference manual because I think you're mixing up the bit and byte order. The value you probably want to use is 0x40004D60 (or 1073761632 if you really must work in decimal).

@brhans Are you sure this is the case? Don't get me wrong, I am not particularly confident in what I am doing, however I went bit by bit and wrote down the proper value. In my question I wrote it going from bit0 to bit31 left -> right. In the actual documentation it goes bit31 -> bit0. If you read my initializer as bit0 -> bit31 left to right it should be the same.

You're writing 0x0200B206 (33600006) to that register. Just look at the LSByte there 0x06 - those 2 bits set to 1 are reserved in the documentation. 0x60 there makes far more sense.

Similarly with the next byte - reverse the bit order of 0xB2 (which sets reserved bits) and you get 0x4D (which does not).

The MSByte reversed from 0x02 (setting another reserved bit) becomes 0x40, which matches the reset values for those bits.

Yup, your absolutely right! My mistake; I do apologize as I am not super experienced with sort of stuff. How about not reading 0 from the data register though? I can't even touch is, so no user error to mess it up. Shouldn't it be at default only 0 bytes?

I don't code in Rust, but it looks to me as though you're creating a set of const pointers and assigning them the addresses 0x00, 0x04 & 0x28 to use to access the PSSI registers. That's never going to work. 0x00, 0x04 & 0x28 are the offsets of those registers from the base address of the peripheral at 0x48020400, so the addresses you need are 0x48020400, 0x48020404 & 0x48020428.

0x00000000, 0x00000004 & 0x00000028 are accessing RAM in the ITCM block of your STM32, not the PSSI (or any other) peripheral.

So the value you think you're reading from PSSI_DR is actually some arbitrary value in the ITCM RAM.

Thank you! I did figure that I was reading and writing to some random places in memory; it appears now that that is certainly the case. You are also correct in your understanding of the Rust code. Can I also ask where you found the base address? I was looking for it but was unable to find it --hence me just trying the offsets alone.

Have you read the MCU reference manual?

@Justme Yes I am using the manual, though for some reason I genuinely couldn't find it. No worries though, I have found it now.

"I would prefer" is not an engineering argument. What problem does using Rust solve in the first place? As it evidently creates a lot of new problems.

@Lundin If this site had only questions with engineering arguments, it would hold only a small fraction of questions. :-D "Because I want" [to learn Rust and use one of my favorite targets] is a fine reason, I imagine.

@thebusybee Except it is explicitly an engineering site and not a hobby site. Meaning good engineering practices should be followed. Including picking the right tools for the project requirements, rather than picking some toy tool that seems fun and then try to shoehorn the requirements into fitting that unsuitable tool. The same can be said about using Arduino and Rasp Pi in a professional setting.

@Lundin I am not adamant on only using Rust. However, the spirit of the question is more of if I were to use Rust. Of course simply not using Rust is always an option, but again, it sort of evades the point of the question. I chose Rust because my development time is far faster than an in C. Additionally, most of my code base is already in Rust, so having some single section entirely in C is awkward. Lastly, the STM32 microcontrollers are very well supported under Rust. Normally, I probably wouldn't even have any issues; unfortunately part of my application may need this niche interface.

As a middle-ground solution (and also out of desperation) I spent much of yesterday getting compiling and calling C functions from Rust working. Now, I have STM32CubeMX generate all the C config code, such as system clocks, PSSI, etc. and I can call it from my Rust application. Then, the idea is that I can proceed as usual with much of the heavy lifting already finished.

@BlueOyster I feel that the language isn't very important at all when doing the most low-level programming like writing drivers. I'm fluent in C more so than assembler, but when I write drivers I might as well write them in assembler and that wouldn't affect my productivity much, since some 95% of it is about reading and understanding the manual and performing testing. Now if a certain language would somehow impact that 5% of the work which is programming, because of poor tool support or whatever, that language is no good for the purpose but a distraction from what's important.

@Lundin You're right, I agree 100%. Often times it does distract from whats important; it's true, at these low-levels a language typically won't have much freedom to differ anyway. Thankfully, I have managed to circumvent my problem entirely: I no longer bother with the PSSI, but instead make one read from the input register port of 16 GPIOs at once --works great!
